# Can I create a function in Google Sheets and use it from a web app Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Apps Script that I put on my site and is adding items to a Google Sheet. But instead of it manipulating the sheet directly, I want it to call a function in the sheet that will do the manipulation. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* have a custom function in a Sheet that will run a custom script and be triggered just like any other built in function, but you can't externally call a specific function in a sheet.  The functions recalculate automatically when you edit the sheet, but you can't trigger them by some other means.  A custom function *can* run a script that does the manipulation.  That part can be done, but calling the function to trigger it from outside the sheet can't be done.

I suppose if you wanted a user to have a sheet open, and somehow trigger a custom function, so they could see the result as they were using the sheet, that would be kind of interesting and useful.

I guess you'd need to somehow be able to trigger someone else's open sheet to recalculate.  I'm not sure if `flush` would do that?

[Google Documentation - Flush](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush())

Comment: Flush does not do this, it applies all pending changes immediately, rather than forcing a recalculation.